# Container of points

Tags: c++, templates

I'm writing a class that stores points with X, Y, Z coordinates, where the specific definition of point is templated:

```
template<class T>
class Foo {
  void add_point(T point);
}
```

Some functions in my class require to access the X,Y,Z components. The issue is that point types (defined by 3rd party libraries) don't have any common interface to access the coordinates. Some of them allow `operator[]` or `operator()`, others access by `.x` or `.x()`.

What approach is better to address that? Should I add another template parameter with a function to access the coordinates? Or should I give up and keep an internal copy of the 3D point in the format I prefer?

Comment: if there are not to many variants you could use template specialization for each of those four variants

Comment: free-function accessor overloads.

Comment: Any reason for the down votes?

Comment: @ChronoTrigger the downvotes are because people like you to show what you have tried, otherwise they feel that they're writing code for you rather than helping you. 
Having said that, I have given you an answer. This technique is tried and tested. For example, it's how `boost::hash` can find a hash function for any class for which you overload the free function `hash_value(X const&)`

Comment: I already mentioned the two approaches that I considered, so I don't think this is one of "those" questions. Anyway, it's not a big deal. I appreciate your answer, I think it's the way to go.

Comment: @ChronoTrigger In addition to what has, already, been said: Asking which one of two ways is _better_ without specifying requirements is subjective. Better _for what_? Hence, some people may, also, think that it is opinion-based question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a template function class who's job is to homogenise the interfaces between all types of point.

Like this:

```
#include <iostream>


// One kind of point
struct PointA
{
    double& operator[](int which) {
        return data[which];
    };
    double data[3];
};

// Another kind of point
struct PointB {
double& x() { return data[0]; }
double& y() { return data[1]; }
double& z() { return data[2]; }
double data[3];
};


// An object which homogenises interfaces
template<class Point>
struct get_coordinate {

    double& x() const {
        return get_x(p);
    }

    Point& p;
};

// some overloads

double& get_x(PointA& p) {
    return p[0];
}

double& get_x(PointB& p) {
    return p.x();
}


template<class Point>
struct Foo
{
    void add_point(Point point) { p = point; }

    double& x() {
        // call through the homogeniser
        return get_coordinate<Point>{p}.x();
    }

    Point p;
};

// test
int main()
{
    Foo<PointA> fa;
    fa.add_point(PointA{{1,2,3}});
    std::cout << fa.x() << std::endl;

    Foo<PointB> fb;
    fb.add_point(PointB{{1,2,3}});
    std::cout << fb.x() << std::endl;
}
```